# DLM Trigonometric seasonality vs trend

Tags: r, trend, seasonality, dlm

I am working with a structural time series model in R using dlm that has both a stochastic (slope and intercept) local trend  and two trigonometric seasonal components (sin and cos pairs). I have difficulty balancing the two.

The main frequencies in my problem arise from several diurnal and semi-diurnal tides. I am using recursive forms of the trig components (e.g. from Harvey) and MLE in the package for estimation. All the innovations are assumed uncorrelated and I assume the cos/sin components for each frequency have the same variance. The MLE estimate is not robust to starting guess, which I think has to do with the ambiguity between trend and seasonality I am seeing in my results.

Just from looking at the data, there is clear growth and decay of the main frequencies. The model doesn't catch this though -- instead, the periodic component stays stationary and an oscillating trend picks up the changes in amplitude as well as some fluctuations at higher frequncies (double the main trig components).

I would like to force the model to evolve the trig components more. I believe this would happen if the trend were more band limited and stayed out of the way. My biggest priority would be representing frequencies lower than the trigonometric ones because these have more predictive value.

Is there an appropriate modification of the trend that would do this? Some kind of differencing? Is there a principled way to constrain the innovation variances so that this happens?

Thanks.